# How to make JSON response from server side

Tags: json, response, server-side

i would like to ask this for my second project of web apps, we were told to design and create javascript app that gets the information from a pre-defined database, and allows to add more data to it, modify it, erase any register, and search. That's pretty easy, but the thing is that our teacher asked that in the moment the browser makes the query to the server and this access the database, the server should return the response in form of a JSON.

I do not know how this is done, thats why i'm asking for a bit of assistance, since i always saw JSONs like libraries that can be add to a Javascript app.

Comment: This is not specific enough. What are you running server-side?

Comment: please research what does each thing is (JSON, PHP, API, REST, AJAX ...), just a little bit, it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick a technology for creating a web accessible server api. 
One common one in the .Net world is WEB API. You can also look into NodeJs (maybe using Express).

Json is really just a data format. It serves the same role as xml, but using a different notation.

Some frameworks like Asp.net Web API do content negotiation and returns data in the format requested in the http header (content type). Other solutions might require you to manually serialize the return data into JSON.

Link http://www.asp.net/web-api